# Parsing JSON event in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, json, elk, filebeat

I have log in following format, it is a plain json with nested fields.

```
{
    "level": "info",
    "message": {
        "req": {
            "headers": {
                "host": "localhost:8080",
                "connection": "keep-alive",
                "x-forwarded-for": "192.168.1.1, 1.1.1.1",
                "x-forwarded-proto": "http"
            },
            "url": "/products?userId=493d0aec-a9a7-42a3",
            "method": "GET",
            "originalUrl": "/products?userId=493d0aec-a9a7-42a3",
            "params": {
                "0": "/products"
            },
            "query": {
                "userId": "493d0aec-a9a7-42a3"
            },
            "body": ""
        },
        "res": {
            "headers": {
                "traceid": "ac586e4e924048",
                "x-correlation-id": "57d7920d-b623-48f8",
                "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
                "content-length": "2",
                "date": "Fri, 08 Mar 2019 09:55:45 GMT",
                "connection": "close"
            },
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "[]"
        },
        "gateway": "internal"
    },
    "correlationId": "57d7920d-b623-48f8",
    "timestamp": "2019-03-08T09:55:45.833Z"
}
```

How can I parse it correctly using Filebeat and Logstash to see all json fields in Kibana as separate (parsed) fields? I have a problem with "message" field which has nested json fields. I have no problem to parse an event which has string in "message", but not json.

My attempts:

1 . I tried to tell Filebeat that it is a json with following configuration:
(and doing nothing on LS side)

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: stdin
  json.keys_under_root: true
  json.add_error_key: true
```

The result is strange for me, because I got "message" as a string in Kibana where all : are replaced with =>

```
{
    "req" => {
        "originalUrl" => "/offers", "params" => {
            "0" => "/offers"
        }, "query" => {}, "body" => "", "headers" => {
            "accept-encoding" => "gzip", "user-agent" => "okhttp/3.8.1", "x-consumer-id" => "f2a6e4cd-2224-4535 .....
```

Other fields outside the "message" are parsed correctly

2 . I did nothing on Filebeat side and use filter in LS:

```
json {   
    source => "message"    
    target => "message_json"    
}
```

Logs are not appeared in Kibana at all, I got following errors in LS:

> [2019-03-08T09:55:47,084][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could
>   not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index",
>   {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"filebeat-6.5.0-2019.03.08-sdx", :_type=>"doc",
>   :routing=>nil}, #],
>   :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-6.5.0-2019.03.08-sdx",
>   "_type"=>"doc", "id"=>"ERS6XGkBgE-US7A6Mvt", "status"=>400,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to
>   parse field [json.message] of type [keyword]",
>   "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get
>   text on a START_OBJECT at 1:461"}}}}} [2019-03-08T09:55:47,085][WARN
>   ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to
>   Elasticsearch. {:status=>400, :action=>["index", {:_id=>nil,
>   :_index=>"filebeat-6.5.0-2019.03.08-sdx", :_type=>"doc",
>   :routing=>nil}, #],
>   :response=>{"index"=>{"_index"=>"filebeat-6.5.0-2019.03.08-sdx",
>   "_type"=>"doc", "id"=>"EhS6XGkBgE-US7A6Mvt", "status"=>400,
>   "error"=>{"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to
>   parse field [json.message] of type [keyword]",
>   "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"illegal_state_exception", "reason"=>"Can't get
>   text on a START_OBJECT at 1:461"}}}}}

This filter works fine for me if the "message" field is a string (not a json).

Any ideas how to parse nested json in "message field"?